# implementing emberjs with laravel project

Tags: laravel, ember.js

i am trying to implement ember.js in a laravel project, so that laravel will be an API server and the front end would be rendered by ember.js any advice on how to go about it ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to watch [this video](https://youtu.be/ZXsQAXx_ao0). It's great and helpful with any combination of frameworks.

In general, you should first install ember-cli and create a fron-end app. Use ember-cli-mirage to simulate an API server. While doing this you can write API documentation as well. Then implement an api using laravel. Deploy both parts somewhere. That's all.

Others may suggest to begin with API, but I insist on implementing frontend first. Because ember is an opinionated framework, especially it's data layer - Ember Data, and it is easier to create API according to ember's standards than adjust ember app to work with API. Other way is possible too, just somewhat harder (more code to write and maintain, more headache).

Someone may as well suggest to create an api and front in the same time. As for me, I think it's easier when you concentrate on each part separately.

Comment: a part of the requirements is that the index page (it is a single page app) will be rendered by the server side any thoughts on how to do that?

Comment: @user605505 what do you mean by "rendered by the server side"? Clarify please.

Comment: the server side would be responsible to render the index page (xhtml), and provide restful API,

Comment: @user605505 render in what meaning? Should it render page with some ready-to-use markup and content before downloading js assets? If so, you can try [ember fastboot](https://github.com/ember-fastboot/ember-cli-fastboot). But I'm not sure it is ready for production apps. Never tried it myself. If you want laravel to serve an empty html file - I don't see any reason for this and do not suggest such mix.

Comment: the rendering could be done in the client side, but the xhtml page should be returned by the server side,

Comment: @user605505 why? I don't see any sense in this requirement. However this requirement will make deployment process harder and may (and will) cause problems with routing on ember side (instead of nice classical urls `your-domain.com/client-route-name` you most probably will be forced to switch to `your-domain.com/#/client-route-name` (hash location type).

Comment: the app itself has one page (index) so the routing is pretty strait forward (at list i hope so )

Comment: @user605505 well, if you insist... You can develop app using ember-cli (it's a build tool for ember, it compiles a lot of modules in 2 minified js files) like it  demonstrated in official tutorial and guide. During development time - use `ember serve` command, it will fire up a local web-server which will serve your app. Than, when you need to deploy, use `ember build`. You will get your app built into `dist` directory. From there you can take index.html and create a laravel's template from it, and all assets will be in `dist/assets` directory. Copy them to your server as well.

Comment: @user605505 that should work. Some details you can find [here](http://culttt.com/2015/04/06/getting-started-with-laravel-and-ember/). I'm not aware about any tools that can make deployment easier, but probably they do exist.

Comment: followed your instructions but encountered  a problem. i couldn't find the App = Ember.Application.create(); line in any of the files, something is missing.

Comment: @user605505 why are you looking for it? I don't think you will find such line in modern versions

Comment: from what i've learned so far about ember is that this command is essential to get ember code running, besides i am trying to make sure that the dependencies are not broken. any advice?

Comment: @user605505 I'm not sure what are you doing and how. Please, read official [tutorial](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/tutorial/ember-cli/) if you didn't yet. There you will find most **recent** information about ember.js.